# How to truncate with ellipsis an inline element in the middle of the line without hyphenation

Tags: html, css

I have

```
<div style="text-align: justify; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden;">
    <span style=" float: right;">
        <span><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-caret-square-o-up fa-fw"></i></a></span>
        <span><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-search fa-fw"></i></a></span>
        <span><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-question fa-fw"></i></a></span>
        <span><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v fa-fw"></i></a>           </span>
    </span>
    <span>
        <span><a><i class="fa fa-bars fa-fw"></i></a></span>
        <span>start long text long text long text long text end</span>
    </span>
    <span style="content: ''; display: inline-block; width: 100%; height: 0; font-size:0; line-height:0;"></span>
</div>
```

as a result, I get what I want

[image: middle trimmed string]

but i use `float: right` on `inline` element. I know that it is auto converted in `block` element. How much is the right decision to trim a string in the middle? How best to implement it?

Comment: What do you mean "how much is the right decision to trim"? Are you asking if it's a good idea for User Experience?

Comment: No. Question about html and css rules.

Comment: Your HTML and CSS are valid.